# How to detect document.open() or document.write() has occured for a document?

Tags: javascript, dom, document.write

I want to do something like adding Event Handler to the frame's document as soon as it loads. But the issue is frame is loading an empty document. So if i am detecting the frame and getting its DOM, the document.URL is returning "about:blank". Now a script in that frame is opening the DOM by using document.open() and writing in it using document.write() (it is overwriting the DOM). So it that case the document reference keeps on waiting it to load but in real the document got loaded.

Can we detect as soon as on a document open() or write() occurs?

Comment: You can't. But maybe the `load` or `ready` events on the document object can be of help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding document.write within a specified scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141839/overriding-document-write-within-a-specified-scope)